# Give a "constructive" proof of the fact that in a metric space the intersection of two open balls is open

Tags: metric-spaces, constructive-mathematics

### **Main Question**

Can someone give a "constructive" proof of the fact that,

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $x,y\in X$. Let $B_d(x,r_x)$ and $B_d(y,r_y)$ be two open balls centered respectively at $x$ and $y$ for $r_x,r_y\in \mathbb{R}^+$. Suppose that $B_d(x,r_x)\cap B_d(y,r_y)\ne \emptyset$ and $z\in B_d(x,r_x)\cap B_d(y,r_y)$. Show that there exists $r_z\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $$B_d(z,r_z)\subseteq B_d(x,r_x)\cap B_d(y,r_y)$$

I have actually tried to give a constructive proof of the fact in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1642752/how-to-resolve-the-apparent-paradox-resulting-from-two-different-proofs) (see the "Second Proof") but after reading the proof carefully I came to the conclusion that it doesn't satisfy my aim because it the second proof doesn't actually "constructs" something, it actually gives a motivation for it. I am not sure whether it is the same thing as a "constructive" argument.

### Relevant Definitions

> **Definition of Open Ball**
>   Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and let $r\in\mathbb{R}^+$. Then the set,
>   $B_d(x, r) := \{y \in X : d(x, y) < r\}$
>   will be said to be *the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$ in the metric space* $(X, d)$.
>
> **Definition of Open Set**
>
> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $U\subseteq X$. Then $U$ will be said to be *$d$-open in $X$* if for all $x\in U$, there exists $r>0$ such that $B_d(x,r)\subseteq U$.

It may be asked that what I have meant by a "constructive" proof. For that purpose, I think that the following will illustrate what I mean by a "constructive" proof.

> **Proposition**
>   Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, $x \in X$ and $r > 0$. Then the open ball $B_d(x,r)$ is open.
>
> ***Proof***
>   Assume an $s>0$  exists such that $B_d(y,s)\subseteq B_d(x,r)$. If $z \in B(y, s)$, we want to show that $d(z, x) < r$. Now,
>   $$d(z, x) \le d(z, y) + d(y, x) <s + d(x, y) < r$$
>   This prompts us to consider $0 < s <r - d(x, y)$. Let $s$ be one such. If
>   $z \in B(y,s)$, then we have
>   $$d(z, x) < d(z, y) + d(y, x) <s + d(y, x) < r$$
>   Thus, $B_d(y, s) \subseteq B_d(x,r)$. Since $y$ is an arbitrary element of $B_d(x , r)$, we are done.

Comment: To simplify the problem a bit, can you show that open balls are open sets constructively? (If you succeed, then you have solved your problem about intersections, because it is easy to show that the intersection of two open sets is open constructively.)

Comment: You forgot the definition of "constructive".

Comment: Does doing by contradiction is "constructive"?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: In the First Proof of the linked post I think that the proof is not constructive because it gives no method as to how one may arrive at the quantity $\min\{r_x-d(x,z),r_y-d(y,z)\}$. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Why do you think the first proof in your other post is not constructive?

Comment: It's the smaller of two positive numbers, both uniquely defined by (and immediately computable from)  the data.

Comment: @RobArthan: I have already said that. Maybe I am having some confused notion of "constructive proof".

Comment: @RobArthan: More specifically it gives no method as to how to arrive at the numbers $r_x-d(x,z)$ and $r_y-d(y,z)$.

Comment: @RobArthan: For that the only way I know is to rely on geometric intuition. I want a proof that is purely "analytic".

Comment: See the extended hint in my answer.

Comment: in your example of a constructive why not take $s = r - d(y, x)$m or $s = (r - d(x, y))/2$. That really would be a constructive argument. In a constructive argument if you say "let $s$ be one such", you have to give a method for picking the $s$. However, there is an agreed formal notion of constructive reasoning (see my answer) and an agreed informal notion within classical reasoning of what constitutes a constructive argument (see David C. Ullrich's answer).

Comment: Your example of a "constructive" proof that an open ball is open is not a proof that an open ball is open, "constructive" or otherwise! In no way does it demonstrate what's required. And it looks very strange to boot - you begin by assuming that $A\subset B$ and much later you say "hence A\subset B$. (There are other similar strangenesses.) Either you have no idea what a proof is or proofs is not really what you're talking about. I suspect the latter: If that's a "constructive proof" I suspect that a "constructive proof" is not a proof, it's an explanation of how one might _find_ a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you give as an illustration of what you mean  by a "constructive proof" actually illustrates that you're not talking about proofs at all; my conjecture is that you're really talking about an explanation of how one might find a proof of something.

Your illustration:

> **Proposition**
> Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, $x \in X$ and $r > 0$. Then the open ball $B_d(x,r)$ is open.
>
> ***Proof***
> Assume an $s>0$  exists such that $B_d(y,s)\subseteq B_d(x,r)$. If $z \in B(y, s)$, we want to show that $d(z, x) < r$. Now,
> $$d(z, x) \le d(z, y) + d(y, x) <s + d(x, y) < r$$
> This prompts us to consider $0 < s <r - d(x, y)$. Let $s$ be one such. If
> $z \in B(y,s)$, then we have
> $$d(z, x) < d(z, y) + d(y, x) <s + d(y, x) < r$$
> Thus, $B_d(y, s) \subseteq B_d(x,r)$. Since $y$ is an arbitrary element of $B_d(x , r)$, we are done.

This is simply not in any way shape or form a proof that open balls are open. To prove that you need to show that if $z\in B(x,r)$ then there exists $s>0$ such that $B(z,s)\subset B(x,r)$. And you simply do not prove that. A proof of that *cannot* begin by *assuming* that $B(z,s)\subset B(x,r)$.

One might regard it as an illustration of how one might find a proof of the proposition. If so it's very badlyy phrased - over and over you say $A$ implies $B$ when what you mean is more something like "We need to prove $A$; now that would follow from $B$" or something.

Assuming that it's actually supposed to be motivation for the proof, one might give a much less incoherent presentation:

> **Motivation:** We need to show that if $z\in B(x,r)$ then there exists $s>0$ so that $b(z,s)\subset B(x,r)$. So we assumme that $z\in B(x,r)$. Now how could we find an $s>0$ as required? We need to show that if $w\in B(z,s)$ then $w\in B(x,r)$, which is to say we need to show there exists $s>0$ with this property: If $d(w,z)<s$ then $d(x,w)<r$. But if we know that $w\in B(z,s)$ then the triangle inequality will show that $$d(x,w)\le d(x,z)+d(z,w)<d(x,z)+s;$$hence we only need to show that there exists $s>0$ such that $d(x,z)+s<r$. Since $d(x,z)<r$ it is clear that $s=r-d(x,z)$ will suffice.

Or something like that - I'm not going to bother proofreading the above. The point is just the difference between starting a supposed "proof" by assuming exactly what is to be proven, and starting an explanation of how one might find a proof by stating clearly what is to be proven, then commenting on what might prove that.

Answer (score 6):

You need to be aware that whatever you mean by "constructive" is very different from what the word usually means. (You "need" to know this, because when you use words meaning something other than what they usually
mean that's going to lead to confusion. Confusion when people read what you write and when others read what you write.)

So for the record, in this post I'm using the word constructive with
its usual meaning - if I'm referring to what you mean, which nobody
quite follows, I'l use scare quotes: "contructive".

In particular there is absolutely nothing non-constructive about the
standard proof that the intersection of two open balls is open. Instead of
telling Brian that the proof is not constructive, you'd be better off
trying to understand how it *is* *constructive*; this might help you
clarify for yourself the difference between constructive and "constructive".

Consider the following two locutions:

1. The set $A$ is non-empty.
2. Let $x\in A$; then [blah blah blah whatever].

As far as I can tell from your comments, you seem to feel that
going from (1) to (2) is somehow not "constructive". But people who
talk about *constructive* this and that do not object to arguing as
in (2), if (1) is given: (1) *means* that there exists $x\in A$, and
nobody but you sees any harm in saying "ok, since we're given that there
exists $x\in A$, let's assume that $x\in A$".

Where actual constructivists differ from most mathematicians is in how, for example, one might *establish* (1) in the first place; for example most people would say that deriving a contradiction from $A=\emptyset$ counts as a proof of (1), while a constructivist would say no, that's not enough, to show that $A$ is nonempty you have to "construct" or otherwise explicitly exhibit an element of $A$. But nobody but you finds anything non"constructive" in passing from (1) to (2), once (1) has been established, or if (1) is *given*.

Similarly with these open balls. Consider

3. $x\in B(y,r)$.
4. $\delta=r-d(x,y)>0$.

Your objection to deriving (4) from (3) seems incoherent to the rest of us; if the objection has something to do with something being not "constructive" fine, we don't know what that means so we can't say But it's a *fact* that deriving (4) from (3) is perfectly acceptable *constructively*. Because $d(x,y)<r$ is simply what (3) *means*! If we're *given* (3) then  your idea that we need to "construct"  $d(x,y)$ seems simply incoherent.

Comment: "If we're given (3) then your idea that we need to "construct" $d(x,y)$ seems simply incoherent."- from where did you get this impression about my idea? Also, how did you get $\delta$? By hit and trial? by geometric intuition? If not then how?

Comment: That said, after reading your answer I realize that my understanding of "constructive" proofs is really weird. Can you suggest an(some) better word(s) so that I may modify the post?

Comment: @user170039 I got that idea from when you said that the standard proof, the one in Brian's answer, was not "constructive".  I probably didn't hit the nail on the head regarding _why_ you feel it's not "constructive", but whatever your reason is it makes no sense to the rest of us, in exactly the same way as it _would_ make no sense if you _were_ saying what I mis-represented you as saying. Can I suggest a better word? No, because I really don't understand what you _do_ mean by "constructive".. One of the first comments asked you to define the word and you never did.

Comment: @user170039 The standard proof that the intersection of two balls is open _is_ perfectly constructive. Whatever "constructive" means, if that's not a "constructive" proof it's hard to see how anyone can ever give a "constructive' proof of _anything_. Which btw is a big difference between "constructive" and _constructive_. Constructivists prove all sort of things, and non-contructivists, ie people who admit the validity of non-constructive reasoning, nonetheless often find a constuctive proof preferable. Not so with "constructive", at least not until you can explain what the word means...

Comment: I can give an outline of the proof that I think will be acceptable to me. Let us assume
that such $r_z > 0$ exists and let $u \in B_d(z, r_z)$. Then,
$$d(x, u) \le d(x, z) + d(z, u) < d(x, z) + rz$$
Now observe that if such an $r_z$ exists and we need to have $u\in B_d(z, r_z) \implies u \in Bd(x, r_x)$ then it can be achieved
if (although it may not be the only possible way) $d(x, z)+r_z<  r_x$. Similar argument will lead us to $d(y, z)+r_z <ry$.
This shows that one **possible** range of values for $r_z$ may be taken as $(0, \min\{r_x − d(x, z), r_y − d(y, z)\}]$ if it exists at
all.

Comment: Then we choose an $r_z\in (0,\min\{r_x-d(x,z),r_y-d(y,z)\}$ and show by easy computation that it indeed proves that $B_d(z,r_z)\subseteq B_d(x,r_x)\cap B_d(y,r_y)$ and we will be done.

Comment: @user170039 "I can give an outline of the proof that I think will be acceptable to me. " You _think_? If _you're_ not sure what you mean by "constructive" then there simply is no such concept. Because the concept certainly does not exist in anyone else's head. Whatever, in any case the proof you give doesn't help until you explain why it counts as more "constructive". And/or _why_ the standard proof is _not_ "constructive".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35411/discussion-between-user-170039-and-david-c-ullrich).

Comment: The other proof is not "constructive" because it doesn't give us a method to find out the possible range of $r_z$ that this argument does.

Comment: @user170039 I'm actually dropping it, until you give us that definition. Because at this point, whatever you do mean by "constructive", I see absolutely no reason why that should be of any interest to anyone. (Again, as opposed to _constructive_ - "everyone" often finds a _constructive_ proof preferable.)

Comment: @user170039 That seems like a wacky requirement. By definition we need to show that there exists an $r$ with a certain property - nothing in the definition of "open" says anything about finding the possible range or $r$. That requirement must be part of the definition of "constructive". But you haven't given us that definition. So every single thing you say about this is totally meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: in constructive reasoning the data (i.e., the objects appearing in the assumptions of your theorem) are given constructively. A real number for example, would be given as a [computable real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number). A metric space $(X, d)$ would be given as a pair of computable functions: one that tests for membership of $X$ and one that calculates $d(x, y)$ for $x, y \in X$. An open set $A$ would be given as a pair of computable functions: one that tests for membership of $A$ and one that given $x \in A$ returns a computable real $r > 0$ such that $B(x, r) \subseteq A$.  Hence the standard proofs of the following facts

- an open ball is an open set
- the intersection of two open sets is an open set

are constructive, since the values you need as witnesses in the proof are computable functions of the input data.

An example of a non-constructive proof is the existence of the supremum of a non-empty bounded above set $X$. The data would comprise the membership test for $X$, an element of $X$ and a bound for $X$. The existence of [Specker sequnces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specker_sequence) shows that there no way to compute the supremum from this data.

Comment: I have provided a "constructive" proof of the fact that open balls are open sets.