# Proof that $U\times V$ is open in the metric space $X\times Y$?

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

**Problem.**

> Let $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ be two metric spaces and let $U\subseteq X$ and $V\subseteq Y$ such that $U$ and $V$ are respectively open in $X$ and $Y$. Show that $U\times V$ is open in $(X\times Y,d_{X\times Y})$. Where $d_{X\times Y}((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=\max \{d_X(x_1,x_2),d_Y(y_1,y_2)\}$ for all $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)\in X\times Y$.

**Proof.**

> Since $U\subseteq X$ and $U$ is open, for all $x\in U$ we can say that there exists $r_x>0$ such that the set $B_{d_X}(x,r_x)\subseteq  U$ will be an open ball in $U$. Similarly the set $B_{d_Y}(y,r_y)\subseteq V$ will be an open ball in $V$.
>
> Let $r=\min\{r_x,r_y\}$. Now we observe that,
>
> \begin{align}(x_0,y_0)\in B_{d_{X\times Y}}((x,y),r)\cap (U\times V)&\implies d_{X\times Y}((x,y),(x_0,y_0))<r\\&\implies \max\{d_X(x,x_0),d_Y(y,y_0)\}<r\\&\implies (d_X(x,x_0)<r) \land (d_Y(y,y_0)<r)\\&\implies (x_0\in B_{d_X}(x,r))\land (y_0\in B_{d_Y}(y,r))\\&\implies (x_0,y_0)\in B_{d_X}(x,r)\times B_{d_Y}(y,r)\end{align}
>
> So it follows that, $$B_{d_{X\times Y}}((x,y),r)\cap (U\times V)\subseteq B_{d_X}(x,r)\times (B_{d_Y}(y,r)\subseteq U\times V$$Now since $B_{d_{X\times Y}}((x,y),r)\cap (U\times V)$ is an open ball (this follows from [the definition of an open ball](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1642752/how-to-resolve-the-apparent-paradox-resulting-from-two-different-proofs)) in $U\times V$ (it is easy to show that $B_{d_{X\times Y}}((x,y),r)\cap (U\times V)\subseteq U\times V$) we can say that $U\times V$ is [open](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1642752/how-to-resolve-the-apparent-paradox-resulting-from-two-different-proofs) in $X\times Y$ and we are done.

Would there be any problem if we take $r=\max\{r_x,r_y\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your proof is you did not tell us what definition of "open" you are using. There are several different definitions, the one usually used in metric spaces is:

> $V\subset X$ is open if for every $x\in V$ there exists some $r$ such that $B(x,r)\subseteq V$.

Now if you are using this definition, you need to start with an arbitrary element $(x,y)\in U\times V$, and find the radius $r$ such that $B_{d_{X\times Y}}((x,y),r)$ is a subset of $U\times V$.

You didn't do that, so your proof is wrong, because you did not prove the inclusion at all. You did provide some $r$, but that $r$ is more or less arbitrary (since $r_x$ and $r_y$ are both arbitrary) and not good enough.

---

Maybe you are using some other definition of *open*, but you need to tell us which one, because right now, I don't understand your proof. The statement $B_{d_{X\times Y}}((x,y),r)\cap (U\times V)\subseteq (U\times V)$ is trivially true, since $A\cap B\subset B$ is always true. Why would this imply that $U\times V$ is open?

What definition of "open" are you even using?

---

**After edit**:

Your proof is still very confusing. See, you start with

> "...Let $B_{d_X}(x,r_x)$ be an open ball in $X$...",

which implies that you already decided on what the value $r_x$ will be.

But then, you say

> "...there exists $r_x>0$..."

which is confusing. You can't just now decide on a new value of $r_x$.

Furthermore, you say:

> "exists $r_x$ such that $B(x,r_x)\cap U$ is an open ball in $U$"

This is true, however, by definition, this is true **even if $U$ is not an open set!**. What you really want is

> "exists $r_x$ such that $B(x,r_x)$ is a subset of $U$."

---

**After second edit**:

Still not good. You have proven that $B_{d_{X\times Y}}((x,y),r)\cap (U\times V)$ is a subset of $U\times V$, but that is trivially true (since, as I said, $A\cap B$ is **always** a subset of $B$), and that fact alone **does not** imply that $U\times V$ is open.

*For example, $B(1,2)\cap [0,1]$ is a subset of $[0,1]$, but that does not mean that $[0,1]$ is an open set in $\mathbb R$.*

What you need to prove is that there exists some ball in $X\times Y$ which:

1. Contains $(x,y)$
2. Is a subset of $U\times V$.

You still haven't done that.

Comment: I have edited the proof slightly. Does it seem clearer?

Comment: @user170039 I still don't see what definition of "open" you are using.

Comment: It is the definition you have given (and I linked in the post).

Comment: @user170039 I expanded my answer with two more comments.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I have edited the proof again. In short the main argument of the proof can be said as, let $(x,y)\in U\times V$ and show that $B_{d_{X\times Y}}((x,y),r)\subseteq U\times V$. This shows that $U\times V$ is open in $X\times Y$ since $B_{d_{X\times Y}}((x,y),r)$ is an open ball.

Comment: But do you really need $B(x,r_x)\subseteq U$? I think that the argument works fine even if $B(x,r_x)\not\subseteq U$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @user170039 Well, take $X=\mathbb R$, and take $U=[0,1]$. I believe we agree that $U$ is not open in $X$ (with the standard metric). However,  if I take any $x\in[0,1]$, then the set $B(x,10)\cup [0,1]$ is equal to $[0,1]$, and $[0,1]$ is **an open set in $U$**!

Comment: @user170039 You **have** to follow definitions, and the definition says: "$U\subset X$ is open if for every $x\in U$, there exists an $r_x>0$ such that $B(x,r_x)$ is a subset of $U$." That's the definition, and that's what you have to prove. So your proof is still wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35590/discussion-between-user-170039-and-5xum).

Comment: @user170039 Let's not, because chat does not allow for latex formatting.

Comment: Proof has been edited again.

Comment: @user170039 So has the answer.

Comment: But isn't $B_{d_{X\times Y}}((x,y),r)\cap (U\times V)$ a ball in $X\times Y$ such that- 1. $(x,y)\in B_{d_{X\times Y}}((x,y),r)\cap (U\times V)$ and 2. $B_{d_{X\times Y}}((x,y),r)\cap (U\times V)\subseteq U\times V$?

Comment: @user170039 It might be, but you didn't prove that it is. You only proved that it's intersection with $U\times V$ is a subset of $U\times V$.

Comment: I say so because I have recently done the following exercise, "Let $A$ be a nonempty subset of a metric space $(X, d)$. Let
us continue to denote by the same letter $d$ the induced metric on $A$. Let
$B_A (a, r)$ denote the open ball in the metric space $(A, d)$ centred at $a \in A$
and radius $r > 0$. Show that $B_A(x,r) = B(x,r) \cap A$, where $B(x, r)$
stands for the open ball in $X$ centred at $x$ and radius $r$."

Comment: @user170039 That exercise cannot directly help you. And even if you use it, you have to **reference** it in the proof. What you need to show is that your ball is a **subset** of $U\times V$. You **still** haven't done that.

Comment: But doesn't it follow trivially?

Comment: @user170039 If it follows trivially, you can write it down rigorously in 3 lines or fewer. Can you?

Comment: @user170039 Also, an overall hint: If you have to ask yourself if something is trivial, then clearly it is not trivial.

Comment: @user170039 I'll be AFK for a couple of hours, so good luck!